# codeigniter download problem

Tags: codeigniter

when using download helper in Ci, I get file download pop up as page load , how do i stop that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working as intended, if you want to stop it, stop using the download helper.

the download helper sends the appropriate headers so that the file is forced to download to the users desktop/downloads

what are you trying to do ?

*edit*
Ok so say your controller is called "download" and your method is called "view" which displays links to your downloads like this:

`mysite.com/download/process/foo.pdf`

create a method in your `download` controller called `process`

```
function process($file)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $data = file_get_contents("my-downloads/$file"); // Read the file's contents
    force_download($file, $data);            
}
```

untested but it should work

you will want some validation etc.

so the user views the downloadable files on `downloads/view` and when they click a link, they go to the `process` method to download the file.

you will probably want a redirect or similar after the file download starts, and i expect you could do it with AJAX so the user never leaves the page.

Comment: I want users to download file only when they click download link

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function do_download($file_name="")
{
    $file_path = 'custom/uploads/project/'.$file_name;
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file_path);
}
```